# Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

When the user completes the registration process, I want to redirect her to the login page, where I get the following error.

Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'accounts'

What method should I use to solve this error?

```
class RegisterUser(APIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.POST)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts:login')
```

Comment: It should be either `return redirect('accounts:login')` or `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can try this way:

Change this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts:login')
```

To:

```
return HttpResponseRedirec('/accounts/login/')
```

Try and see if it solves the error

Answer (score 1):

It should be either:

```
return redirect('accounts:login')
```

or:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))
```